# What is the explanation of why my JSON object is not being defined?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asynchronous

I have had a look at the following questions, with negative results:

- [I'm not quite understanding this asynchronous nature](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51391850/im-not-quite-understanding-this-asynchronous-nature)
- [Javascript asynchronous nature](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64220452/javascript-asynchronous-nature)
- [Why is the object not being updated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55369951/why-is-the-object-not-being-updated)

My question was labeled as being a duplicate of, or having answers in, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4057440/is-chromes-javascript-console-lazy-about-evaluating-arrays), but it's absolutely not because the same issue is seen in Firefox - not a webkit issue.

The short version is that I thought to define all my JS functions in one file, and essentially use all my calls and eventlisteners in another file, loaded at the end and encapsulated in a `.ready()` function.

Let's say that in file_01.js, I have a this function:

```js
function load_some_data() {
    let results_json = {};
    let query_string_objects = {
        this_thing: "query_string_one...",
        that_thing: "query_string_two...",
        the_other_thing: "query_string_three...",
    }
    for (let some_thing in query_string_objects) {
        $.ajax({
            method: "GET",
            data: query_string_objects[some_thing],
            url: "./query_processor.php",
            success: get_results,
        });
        function get_results(results) {
            results_json[some_thing] = (JSON.parse(results));
        }
    }
    console.log('Within load_some_data: ');
    console.log(results_json);
    return results_json;       
}
```

then in file_02.js, let's say I have this:

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
    let stored_data = load_some_data();
    console.log('After function call and assignment: ');
    console.log(stored_data);
    console.log(stored_data.this_thing);
});
```

And the output/access is confusing to me. I understand clearly why the console statements appear how they do: inside the function rendering first then after from the file_02 console.log statement. But why are the JSON objects empty **until** I click to expand the object and then there comes that statement: 'This value was evaluated....'?

[image]

[image]

[image]

I am including the phenomenon in Firefox as well. Additionally I have tested the syntax of the `console.log(stored_data.this_thing);`,  with `console.log(stored_data[this_thing]);` and `console.log(stored_data['this_thing']);` with the same result.

The error below the console outputs, seen/experienced is unrelated - it's a ChartJs config thing I am getting wrong.

[image]

Comment: http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/

Comment: Here is what [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console/log) says: _«Don't use console.log(obj), use console.log(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj))` This way you are sure you are seeing the value of obj at the moment you log it. Otherwise, many browsers provide a live view that constantly updates as values change.»_ ("Live view" means a weak reference is created toward the original object and changes made to the object will be reflected within the console)

Comment: Console.log appends `undefined` line: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14633968/chrome-firefox-console-log-always-appends-a-line-saying-undefined